# How to use 'less than/Greater than' formula with negative numbers in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to create a formula which calculates if a number is in between two numbers. If both are positive numbers it works, however, if one is negative it always returns false why is this and what can I do to fix it?

My formula is as follow

```
=IF(AND(W25<=AA13,AA13<=V25),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Below is an example of the numbers and the cells

```
-10 <= 0.326 <= 100

(W25)  (AA13)   (V25)
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT
I've split it up to see which one is causing issues it is:

```
=AA13>=W25
```

I typed in =ISNUMBER(W25) and it's come back with false

Comment: For me, the value is true. Please step into the formula in order to understand what step is going wrong ("formula" ribbon, "Evaluate Formula", ...).

Comment: Works fine here. By the way, you don't need the IF since AND returns TRUE/FALSE already: `=AND(W25<=AA13,AA13<=V25)`

Comment: break the formula down to [=IF(W25<=AA13,TRUE,FALSE)] & [=IF(AA13<=V25),TRUE,FALSE)] ,  u can see which one is giving the problem from there.. (pls share the outcome.. interested to know if it solves/not)

Comment: Thanks for that tip Rory! And thanks P. I've split it up and it the -10 <= 0.326 that is returning false still. I've tried AA13>=W25 (0.326>=-10) this is returning false, but if I do AA13=<W25 (0.326=<-10) it returns true?! Makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Check the negative sign in your data. I can recreate this if the -10 is in text format, or if the negative sign was copied from somewhere else that replaced the hyphen with the ascii character with the code of 150.

Comment: Ah you're on to something here.... so if I use the value -10 instead of the cell it works. So the original cell was actually within a bracket [100/-10]. I then used the formula =MID(Y3,FIND("/",Y3)+1),FIND("]",Y3)-FIND("/",Y3)-1). This then would come back with -10 which I was using for the formula, so there is something wrong with it here?

Comment: Yep. That formula is working with strings/text. Try wrapping it in a NUMBER() function to convert it to a number.

Comment: Sorry, Answered this on my mobile. The function is NUMBERVALUE(). Please mark this as answered if this solved your issue.